# Question on Pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The maximum tension in the string of the pendulum is three time the minimum tension.If x(angle) is the amplitude of the pendulum then find cos(x)

Comment: the minimum would be -mgcosx but i am confused about what would be the maximum tension

Comment: I agree that the minimum tension is when the pendulum is turning around at $x$. Where is the pendulum when the tension is at maximum? What are the forces acting on it there?

Comment: when pendulum is at the normal .the forces are g and force due to its acceleration

Comment: The only force is $mg$? so according to $F=ma$ the pendulum accelerates towards the floor? or is there another force?

Comment: what about the centrifugal force

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14827/discussion-between-rob-and-achal-kumar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of the swing, the force on the string is the sum of the force of gravity and the force needed to keep the mass moving in a circular orbit ($F=\frac{m v^2}{l}$). At the extreme end of the swing, the only tension is due to a vertical *component* of the force of gravity ($mg cos\theta$). From $m g l (1-cos\theta)$ you can compute the potential energy at the top of the swing - this becomes kinetic energy $\frac12mv^2$at the bottom of the swing.

Those are all the components you need to put together your solution.

Do these concepts make sense - or do they need further elaboration?